# CSS - Margin Top property does not work

Tags: css, properties, margin, line-breaks

I'm trying to create blank space between a table element and a paragraph/link element. Here's what it currently looks like.

```
table first column           table last column
table first row




table last row
link
```

Here's what I'd like it to look like

```
table last row


link
```

I've tried many different things, and none of them worked. I tried embedded ruby and adding \n escape characters. I've tried using multiple break tags inside my paragraph element. I've even tried selecting the element and using the CSS property for margin-top which is supposed to create white space before the element. Here is my css.

```
#submit {
background-color: blue;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.3em;
margin-top: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
height: auto;
width: auto;
}
```

every other property works except for the one I want most margin-top. I've even tried adding margin-bottom to the table element, and that didn't work either. For reference, I'll post my table css as well.

```
#table {
text-align: left;
}

th {
background-color: #FFCC99;
&:hover {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
};
}

#title, #console, #genre, #release {
background-color: #66FFFF;
&:hover {
    background-color: #33FF00;
    font-weight: bold;
};
```

I could try continuing to beat my head against a brick wall, but I'm tired of that, so I'm asking for help here.

I pasted the HTML directly from the browser here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Games</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" id="logo">Games Database</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="/games">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/static_pages/help">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/users/new">Sign up</a>
          <li><a href="/signin">Sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


<h1><span id = "red">Games</span> <span id = "yellow">Database</span></h1>
  <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id = "title_id"><a href="/games?sort=title">Title</a></th>
        <th id = "console_id"><a href="/games?sort=console">Console</a></th>
        <th id = "genre_id"><a href="/games?sort=genre">Genre</a></th>
        <th id = "release_id"><a href="/games?sort=released_on">Release Date</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Tetris</td>
        <td id = "console">NES</td>
        <td id = "genre">Puzzle</td>
        <td id = "release">1984</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/16">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/16/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/16" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Wii Sports</td>
        <td id = "console">Wii</td>
        <td id = "genre">Sports</td>
        <td id = "release">2006</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/17">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/17/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/17" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Super Mario Bros.</td>
        <td id = "console">NES</td>
        <td id = "genre">Platform</td>
        <td id = "release">1985</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/18">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/18/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/18" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Mario Kart Wii</td>
        <td id = "console">Wii</td>
        <td id = "genre">Racing</td>
        <td id = "release">2008</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/19">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/19/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/19" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Grand Theft Auto V</td>
        <td id = "console">Playstation 3</td>
        <td id = "genre">Action_adventure</td>
        <td id = "release">2013</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/23">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/23/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/23" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Minecraft</td>
        <td id = "console">Microsoft Windows</td>
        <td id = "genre">Sandbox</td>
        <td id = "release">2009</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/24">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/24/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/24" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2</td>
        <td id = "console">Xbox360</td>
        <td id = "genre">First Person Shooter</td>
        <td id = "release">2009</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/25">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/25/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/25" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class = color>
        <td id = "title">Metroid</td>
        <td id = "console">NES</td>
        <td id = "genre">Action-adventure</td>
        <td id = "release">1986</td>
    </div>
        <td><a href="/games/28">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/games/28/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/28" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p>
<break>
<a href="/games/new" id="submit">Add a new game</a>
</p>

  <div class = "footer">
    <a href="/games">Home</a>
    <a href="/static_pages/about">About</a>
    <a href="/static_pages/contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your html or better a jsfiddle

Comment: Looks like that's going to be difficult. This is a Ruby on Rails project and involves multiple stylesheets, embedded ruby and bootstrap. I'll see what I can do though.

Comment: All you need to do is view source in the browser and post the *generated* HTML. So far, you've left out the important bit—the link that you are trying to style!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing here without seeing your HTML, but you probably need to set your link to `display: block` or `display: inline-block` for the margin to apply.

By default, anchor elements are set to `display: inline`, and top/bottom margin doesn't apply to inline elements.

Comment: well, I imagine this involves the box model, where every element on the page is supposed to be a box. The problem is most likely the table block. That's likely effecting my link element. Well, that's just my guess at least

Comment: If you post the HTML related to the link, we can give a definitive answer. Just try giving it `display: block`.

Comment: I just tried with display:block and it worked. Thank you for your help, this problem gave me a lot of trouble

Comment: Cool! However, I recommend you remove `<break>`, as that's not HTML (the correct code is `<br`>, but you don't need it anyhow). If I'd seen your HTML beforehand, I would have recommended putting a class on the parent `p` itself and placing the top margin on that. It's not a biggie, but still, that's a nicer option. Otherwise, people will be able to click anywhere in that `p` to trigger the link—which you may or may not want.